# Getting class name from BatchJob?

Tags: asyncapexjob

i have tried AsyncApexJob to get class name which is being executed in that job...but unable to get it..
i need help on this

thanks

Comment: PepeFloyd not able to find way for this ...but to meet stackexchange standard i have written..is there a way to get it..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be able to get the class name by doing this:

```
Select  Status, ApexClassId, ApexClass.Name  From AsyncApexJob
```